# How to properly build a dynamic pagination component using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a re-usable component to be used for pagination.

Before making you guys read more, this is how my state looks like:
[image]

I'm calling it from a component where I'm fetching post from MongoDB.

From there I'm having troubles with useEffect to make the changes and with my Pagination component that I'm not even sure if I'm building it properly.

This is my useEffect:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const page = parseInt(params.get('page')) || 1;
const limit = parseInt(params.get('limit')) || 1;
const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
const endIndex = page * limit;
// const currentPosts = posts.slice(endIndex, startIndex);
const currentPosts = Object.entries(posts).slice(endIndex, startIndex);
console.log(currentPosts);

useEffect(() => {
  getPosts(null, null, page, limit);
  getCurrentProfile();
}, [getPosts, getCurrentProfile]);

// Change page
const paginate = pageNumber => page(pageNumber);
```

this is the component I'm calling inside the loop that is fetching the posts.

```
<Pagination
  limit={limit}
  totalPosts={posts.data.length}
  paginate={paginate}
/>
```

Finally this is how I'm working with the component, it is obviously still a work in progress.

```
import React from 'react';

const setPagination = ({ limit, totalPosts, paginate }) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts / limit); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className='pagination'>
        {pageNumbers.map(number => (
          <li key={number} className='page-item'>
            <a
              onClick={() => paginate(number)}
              href={`?page=${number}&limit=${limit}`}
              className='page-link'
            >
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default setPagination;
```

Right now, I'm trying to make it work with query strings from my url:
`http://localhost:3000/posts?page=1&limit=1`

Can anyone guide me on the logic that I'm missing? I'm having a headache with this xD.

**EDIT**:Sorry I did not make it clear. This is the problem:
[image]
Should not it create more pages?

Comment: Where is the problem, or better, what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that it is only creating one single page.